# nullpointer exception requesDispatcher

Tags: java

```
String fn=request.getParameter("fn");
request.setAttribute("eno",eno);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("../WebRoot/displayperson.jsp");

rd.forward(request, response);
```

it will not cal the jsp's

Comment: your getRequestDispatcher path may not be correct or path does not exists

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) states

> a RequestDispatcher object that acts as a wrapper for the resource at the specified path, or null if the servlet container cannot return a RequestDispatcher

It seem the path you are providing does not exist or cannot be resolved the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

RequestDispatcher  works only with in the application. You can not give any other application path. You have to give exact path(Exact Match url) of your jsp.

If you are able to access your jsp(displayperson.jsp) from your browser url followed by application name then 
RD("/displayperson.jsp") is enough to forward.